# Output 'man grep' command into a file

Tags: linux

I have practiced in using command line in CentOS6.
I tried to create file, which content would be the output of command `man grep`. Also I used command `man` with `col -b` option to save file as Text-Only. All of this must be in one command.
 I tried to do like this:

`grep man grep | col -b > output.txt`

But it didn't work.

What is the proper way to save output of command `man grep` as Text-Only file with using option `col -b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you really need this:

```
man grep | col -b > output.txt
```

Why do you need to call `grep` in the first place?

Other, hacky way using `grep`:

```
man grep | grep -v somephrasethatwontoccur | col -b > output.txt
```

But, truly, it makes no sense. `grep -v` looks for lines without the specified phrase.